# How simulate signal transmission in networks using python

Tags: python, networking

I need to simulate signal transmission in Erdos-Renyi graph, where I generate a graph and next with some probability I will establish some active and inactive nodes. And after that I should choose active nodes and check neighbour inactive nodes and with some probability make a signal transmission.

Is any tools to do that and vizualize?

Comment: Asking to provide you with any tools or other off-site resources is, unfortunately, off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ForceBru maybe anybody knows about libraries, that can help to do this

Comment: @PetrPetrov maybe. But it's still off-topic for SO.